# IntelliJ - labels in Debugging Mode

Tags: debugging, settings, intellij-15

When I use the debugger in IntelliJ, I get the values of the variables inside the code lines (see text in gray in the attached picture). I would like to cancel this feature. Do you know how to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Debug tool window toolbar click the ***Settings*** icon and deselect the ***Show Values Inline***:

[image: deselect value inline]